# Django Internationalization---compilemessages error:AttributeError: module 'locale' has no attribute 'normalize'

Tags: python, django, internationalization, locale

I am just before finishing line and feel that i don't finish yet! I created and compiled all of the messages in order to have a site with 2 languages and i received this error when running the server: AttributeError: module 'locale' has no attribute 'normalize'.

Can someone please help me?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ionutcohen/Dropbox/PycharmProjects/chn/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/ionutcohen/Dropbox/PycharmProjects/chn/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/ionutcohen/Dropbox/PycharmProjects/chn/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 306, in execute
    parser = CommandParser(None, usage="%(prog)s subcommand [options] [args]", add_help=False)
  File "/Users/ionutcohen/Dropbox/PycharmProjects/chn/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 47, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1633, in __init__
    self._positionals = add_group(_('positional arguments'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/gettext.py", line 606, in gettext
    return dgettext(_current_domain, message)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/gettext.py", line 570, in dgettext
    codeset=_localecodesets.get(domain))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/gettext.py", line 505, in translation
    mofiles = find(domain, localedir, languages, all=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/gettext.py", line 477, in find
    for nelang in _expand_lang(lang):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/gettext.py", line 206, in _expand_lang
    loc = locale.normalize(loc)
AttributeError: module 'locale' has no attribute 'normalize'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is how my locale folder looks like:
[image]

This is the function from gettext.py refered to the error. Seems the first line has the error:

```
def _expand_lang(loc):
    loc = locale.normalize(loc)
    COMPONENT_CODESET   = 1 << 0
    COMPONENT_TERRITORY = 1 << 1
    COMPONENT_MODIFIER  = 1 << 2
    # split up the locale into its base components
    mask = 0
    pos = loc.find('@')
    if pos >= 0:
        modifier = loc[pos:]
        loc = loc[:pos]
        mask |= COMPONENT_MODIFIER
    else:
        modifier = ''
    pos = loc.find('.')
    if pos >= 0:
        codeset = loc[pos:]
        loc = loc[:pos]
        mask |= COMPONENT_CODESET
    else:
        codeset = ''
    pos = loc.find('_')
    if pos >= 0:
        territory = loc[pos:]
        loc = loc[:pos]
        mask |= COMPONENT_TERRITORY
    else:
        territory = ''
    language = loc
    ret = []
    for i in range(mask+1):
        if not (i & ~mask):  # if all components for this combo exist ...
            val = language
            if i & COMPONENT_TERRITORY: val += territory
            if i & COMPONENT_CODESET:   val += codeset
            if i & COMPONENT_MODIFIER:  val += modifier
            ret.append(val)
    ret.reverse()
    return ret
```

Later Edit: I've deleted the init files and now i got this error:

```
  File "/Users/ionutcohen/Dropbox/PycharmProjects/chn/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/Users/ionutcohen/Dropbox/PycharmProjects/chn/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.management.base import (
  File "/Users/ionutcohen/Dropbox/PycharmProjects/chn/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 7, in <module>
    from argparse import ArgumentParser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 93, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext as _, ngettext
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/gettext.py", line 409
    advance to next entry in the seek tables
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Might be wrong, but try deleting the __init__.py files in your locale folder and any sub folder - the locale folder or anything inside it is not meant to be a python module

Comment: @at14 Thank you! I've deleted the init files and now i got this ugly error :(

Comment: You got the new error when trying to run compilemessages? or when trying to access some view or function

Comment: I got the error when trying to run the server "The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: erien���� d"

Comment: Are you explicitly casting something to str ?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same. In PyCharm I had made a directory "locale" (with a `__init__.py` for no reason whatsoever) for my internationalisation and got this message:

`AttributeError: module 'locale' has no attribute 'normalize'`

This is due to the fact it is looking for a Python module "locale" but that is masked by your Django directory "locale".

Either remove the `__init__.py` and/or rename your directory "locale". I did both... "To stitch something twice is to stich it well" as we say in Holland.

It seems that everywhere on the net people use "locale" as directory for their internationlization. Hmm.. it now seems to me a bit like making a class with the name "Class" or a SQL table with the name "Table". I have seen in done, at times it works, I would never recommend it though.

Comment: Django core uses the directory `locale` and `__init__.py`. https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/conf/locale